# Password stretching in PuTTY

Tags: passwords, windows, ssh

Does PuTTY use password stretching when passphrase protecting my SSH keys?

If it doesn't by default, how can I make it do so?

Answer (score 0):

Your key can be attacked without using Putty as it does not reside inside a Putty-controlled environment but rather an OS-controlled environment.  Thus adding complexity to Putty password interaction with your key will not provide protection for the key.

Comment: I know that. I'm talking about key stretching for making brute forcing for the block cipher key more difficult.